# Not getting any warning when returning NULL as object

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, compiler-warnings, clang++

I don't understand why I don't get a warning (with g++ or clang++) for returning a NULL as an object in `newtstr()` below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string newstr();

int main()
{
        string s = newstr();
        cout << s << endl;
        return 0;
}

string newstr()
{
        return NULL;
}
```

.

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic testptr.cpp
$
```

I do, however, get a runtime error:

```
$ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted
$
```

.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.0
```

Comment: you've tagged this clang++. Does this really apply to clang, too?

Comment: Why do you expect an warning? It is a valid construct.

Comment: @ZDF OP's either not aware of the implicit `const char*` cast, or he'd expect his compiler to see "hey, that's a static expression that gives me a zero pointer with which the `string` ctor tries to do stuff, it should be able to warn me about that!".

Comment: @MarcusMüller It does, surprisingly, even with `-Weverything`

Comment: @ZDF I didn't know about the valid construct (and I think it is rather arcane, after reading it in the accepted post)

Comment: @ChrisGregg not really; see my comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` has a [**constructor** `basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which accepts a `const char*` pointer for constructing a new string (see <sup>(5)</sup>). The line `return NULL;` results in a implicit call to that constructor with a NULL pointer as argument - which is valid code but obviously won't run correctly.

Comment: Ah - thanks! I think this falls into the "there's a lot baked into the C++ std library" category...

Comment: not really, @ChrisGregg. Imagine a world where there's no method of constructing a ´std::string´ from a C style string (which is a ´const char´ array, which for all method calling is inherently converted to a ´const char *´) – it'd be miserably hard to specify strings in your code, because your normal `"text"` string literal is exactly that – a C style string.